# Replace all consecutive repeated letters ignoring specific words

Tags: python, regex, text, preprocessor

I saw plenty of suggestions to remove consecutively repeated letters in a sentence either using re (regex) or .join in python, but I want to have exception for special words.

**E.g.:**

I want this sentence > `sentence = 'hello, join this meeting heere using thiis lllink'`

to be like this > `'hello, join this meeting here using this link'`

knowing that I have this list of words to keep and ignore repetitive letters check: `keepWord = ['Hello','meeting']`

**The two scripts I found useful are:**

- Using .join:

  ```
  import itertools

  sentence = ''.join(c[0] for c in itertools.groupby(sentence))
  ```
- Using regex:

  ```
  import re

  sentence = re.compile(r'(.)\1{1,}').sub(r'\1', sentence)
  ```

I have a solution, but I think there's a more compacted and efficient one. My solution for now is:

```
import itertools

sentence = 'hello, join this meeting heere using thiis lllink'
keepWord = ['hello','meeting']

new_sentence = ''

for word in sentence.split():
    if word not in keepWord:
        new_word = ''.join(c[0] for c in itertools.groupby(word))
        new_sentence = sentence +" " + new_word
    else:
        new_sentence = sentence +" " + word
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you expect in case of `Hellllo`?

Comment: well, I haven't handle this case in my suggestion, this can be resolved by ignoring the 1st occurrence of the letter under `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match the whole words from the `keepWord` list, and only replace sequences of two or more identical letters in other contexts:

```
import re
sentence = 'hello, join this meeting heere using thiis lllink'
keepWord = ['hello','meeting']
new_sentence = re.sub(fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(keepWord)})\b|([^\W\d_])\1+", lambda x: x.group(1) or x.group(), sentence)
print(new_sentence)
# => hello, join this meeting here using this link
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Z9Qj1B)

The regex will look like

```
\b(?:hello|meeting)\b|([^\W\d_])\1+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vsqa8a/1/). If Group 1 matches, its value is returned, else, the full match (the word to keep) is put back.

**Pattern details**

- `\b(?:hello|meeting)\b` - `hello` or `meeting` enclosed with word boundaries
- `|` - or
- `([^\W\d_])` - Group 1: any Unicode letter
- `\1+` - one or more backreferences to Group 1 value

Comment: Great, that did exactly the expected output. Thank you

Comment: @Aisha If you need case insensitive search, add `(?i)` at the start of the regex pattern. Or add the fourth argument to `re.sub`: `re.sub(..., ..., sentence, flags=re.I)`

Answer (score 1):

Although not especially compact, here is a reasonably simple example using regexp: the function `subst` will replace repeated characters with a single one, and then `re.sub` is used in order to call this for each word that it finds.

It is assumed here that because your example `keepWord` list (where first mentioned) has `Hello` in title case but the text has `hello` in lower case, that you want to perform a case-insensitive comparison against the list.  So it will work equally whether your sentence contains `Hello` or `hello`.

```
import re

sentence = 'hello, join this meeting heere using thiis lllink'
keepWord = ['Hello','meeting']

keepWord_s = set(word.lower() for word in keepWord)

def subst(match):
    word = match.group(0)
    return word if word.lower() in keepWord_s else re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', word)

print(re.sub(r'\b.+?\b', subst, sentence))
```

Gives:

```
hello, join this meeting here using this link
```